# Want to display Recently view products in Footer in magento

Tags: magento

I want to display Recently view products in footer .How can I do that?Because I have placed those in page.xml

```
<reference name="footer"> 
   <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

and these in footer

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved :

You have to go to Page.xml and paste this code within the block

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>recently_viewed</type><limit>8</limit></action>
</block>
</block>
```

After that Went to footer.phtml and paste this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>
```

I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Place the below code in footer. No need to change in xml. Paste that any whare you want to show.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: @mainak:  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already configured

```
admin > system > configuration > catalog > recently viewd/compared products
```

& you are enabled to see

```
admin > reports > products > most viewed
```

& tried

```
admin > reports > refresh statistics
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `local.xml` in you current theme and add the below code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

In `footer.phtml` you need to call block like the below:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reports.product.viewed') ?>
```